# Validation : how to check if the file being uploaded is in excel format? - Apache POI

Tags: validation, jsf, apache-poi

Is there any way I can check if the file being uploaded is in excel format? I am using Apache POI library to read excel,  and checking the uploaded file extension while reading the file.

Code snippet for getting the extension

```
String suffix = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile.getName());
```

courtesy [BalusC : uploading-files-with-jsf](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html)

```
String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile.getName());
if ("xls".equals(fileExtension)) {
//rest of the code
}
```

I am sure, this is not the proper way of validation.

**Sample code for browse button**

```
<h:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{sampleInterface.uploadedFile}" 
        valueChangeListener="#{sampleInterface.uploadedFile}" />
```

**Sample code for upload button**

```
<h:commandButton action="#{sampleInterface.sampleMethod}" id="upload" 
value="upload"/>
```

User could change an extension of a doc or a movie file to "xls" and upload,then it would certainly throw an exception while reading the file.

Just hoping somebody could throw some input my way.

Comment: How much validation do you need to do? Just enough to check that someone hasn't uploaded a csv? Enough to know they haven't uploaded a different office file (eg .ppt)? Or enough to know it can be loaded without error (not truncated etc)?

Comment: Yes, most of these kind of scenarios.

Comment: If you want to check for all of these, then your only option is as BalusC says, and try to open it in POI and catch the exceptions if it's in the wrong format. (If you only wanted to do some kinds of simpler checking then there are other options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't check that before feeding it to POI. Just catch the exception which POI can throw during parsing. If it throws an exception then you can just show a `FacesMessage` to the enduser that the uploaded file is not in the supported excel format.

Comment: Hello BalusC, thanks for the response, it did work but its also throwing some method not found exception. method is very well defined but still its throwing an exception

Link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593058/exception-jsf

Comment: What exception exactly are you talking about? Show the stacktrace.

Comment: Wait, the `valueChangeListener` and the `value` attributes have  the same EL expression! This makes no utter sense. I think that you actually don't need the `valueChangeListener` at all. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be more helpful to the poster. Of course you can test before poi.
Regular tests, to be performed before the try/catch, include the following. I suggest a fail-fast approach.

1. Is it a "good" file?

   1. if file.isDirectory() -> die and exit.
   2. if !file.isReadable() -> die and exit.
   3. if file.available <= 100 -> die and exit (includes file size zero)
   4. if file.size >= some ridiculous large number (check your biggest excel file and multiply by 10)
2. File seems good, but is contents like Excel?

   1. Does it start with "ÐÏà" -> if not, die.
   2. Does it contain the text "Sheet"-> if not, die
   3. Some other internal excel bytes that I expected from you guys here.

Comment: The regular tests which you mention there make absolutely no sense on **an uploaded file**. It is always a non-directory, always readable and always "available". The file size is usually configured in uploader settings (e.g. users can upload max 10MB or so). Those tests make maybe sense on a local disk file system pointer, but this isn't the case at all in this particular question. By the way, you're misunderstanding what `available()` does (no worries, almost every starter never understood it). Further your content tests make absolutely no sense. Those are business specific requirements.

Comment: @BalusC so how does one use available() ? And how does one configure uploader settings?

Comment: Read javadoc what it means. If you don't understand it, just don't use it. You don't need it anyway to write an uploaded file.